# Expand only one level in Eclipse search results

Tags: eclipse, search

I'm searching in Eclipse and getting multi results on multiple modules.

When results returns I have option to Expand All.

Also option to [expand a module](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423249) using `*` key

But sometimes I need "high level expanding", just seeing the relevant classes or relevant packages in all modules without seeing the specific code lines.

I expected to open one level at a time.

I didn't find such option, is it achievable somehow? Can this requirements be added as an enhancement to Eclipse?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this.

Comment: @greg-449 is there a way to expand only in one module? can this be added as an enhancement to Eclipse?

Comment: The only expand option is the Expand All. The search code provides a number of APIs but I don't think any of them allows this to be changed easily. So it would have to be a core Eclipse enhancement request - submit on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened an enhancement [Bug 547752 - Add option expand one level at a time in search results](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547752)

You can [vote](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=547752#vote_547752) for it.

I gave 2 options for showing folders relevant to search:

First option is to open one level at a time on every click

Second option is to open all folders not including files in one click

First option is longer to get specific packages/folders

Second option is just open the packages/folders level of relevant files